# Test framework with automated email notification for python

Tags: python, testing, automation, email

I'm looking for a test framework for Python that will automatically email me if a test fails, with the name of the broken test and the broken test output. I understand it's fairly trivial to wrap a testing library in a try/catch block, but I was surprised that I couldn't find frameworks that support this out of the box. Was I not looking hard enough, or am I taking the wrong approach to running tests? I am pretty new to the test process.

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you want your tests run automatically and have the emails sent to you because you aren't there to run them, [buildbot](http://trac.buildbot.net/) is the tool: it can run tests whenever you commit to the repository, and on failure can alert you via email, IRC message, etc.